# How can I store additional information against an attribute?

Tags: attributes

So, I have an attribute, let's call it Brand, and every Brand has a unique attribute itself, let's call it Warranty. What would be the best way of storing these warranties? So far I can think of:

- Storing the warranty information in a helper (but then I'd need to edit code overtime there was a new brand
- Creating another table in my database that stores this information, but I can't think of a mangento-y way to make it editable in the admin section

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new entity in your instance with a CRUD module and make the `brand` attribute use that entity as a source model.
There is a lot of code involved and I cannot put all of it in here.
I can recommend you [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9). It allows you to add custom entities to your magento instance and it will generate the code needed for the CRUD UI of your module.
It also does what you need.
It can make your new entity a product dropdown attribute with a custom source model.
[Documentation can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki)